# Deserialize a json object with an array fails with Default constructor not found for type System.String[]

Tags: json, c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, restsharp

I am having a little trouble trying to deserialize an object within a monotouch project using restsharp.

I have this

```
    RestResponse<List<Product>> response = client.Execute<List<Product>> (request) as RestResponse<List<Product>>;
            if (response.Data != null) {}

    public class Product
{
    public Product () {}
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string[] ParentProductIds {
    get;
    set;
}
```

I'm getting an error of

> Default constructor not found for type System.String[].

My json looks like

```
[ 
    {
    "Id" : "62907011-02f1-440a-92ec-dc35ecf695e0",
    "Name" : "ABC",
    "ParentProductIds" : ["2cedbcad-576a-4044-b9c7-08872de34a96", "3fcd12ce-8117-4ae7-ae4d-f539e4268e4d"]
    }, 
    {
    "Id" : "3fcd12ce-8117-4ae7-ae4d-f539e4268e4d",
    "Name" : "Name 1",
    "ParentProductIds" : null
    }
]
```

Is it due to the null ParentProductId ?

Can anyone advise what I need to do to be able to accept null arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone else having the same problem using a List<> instead works fine.

```
public List<string> ParentProductIds {
    get;
    set;
```

Answer (score 10):

The Key of this issue is that RestSharp uses its own internal Json Serializer/Deserializer, which does not support deserialization of array objects (ParentProductIds in your case). It does support deserialization of List (Generics) objects. Although your solution is completely valid, I believe that there are some scenarios in which one much rather prefer to leave the array instead of using generics. To do so, I continued to use RestSharp for my rest requests, but used JsonConvert from James Newton-King (JSon.Net from NuGet) to deserialize from the response.Content.

Hence you would add Json.Net to your project, add the corresponding using statement  and use the following to deserialize your response:

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
List<Product> product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response.Content);
```

The additional benefit is that JSon.Net is a much more efficient serializer, so the code runs in general faster.